# Sending mails with attachment via NodeJS

Tags: email, node.js, attachment

Is there any library for NodeJS for sending mails with attachment?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty simple, 
I use nodemailer: `npm install nodemailer --save`

```
var mailer = require('nodemailer');
mailer.SMTP = {
    host: 'host.com', 
    port:587,
    use_authentication: true, 
    user: 'you@example.com', 
    pass: 'xxxxxx'
};
```

Then read a file and send an email :

```
fs.readFile("./attachment.txt", function (err, data) {

    mailer.send_mail({       
        sender: 'sender@sender.com',
        to: 'dest@dest.com',
        subject: 'Attachment!',
        body: 'mail content...',
        attachments: [{'filename': 'attachment.txt', 'content': data}]
    }), function(err, success) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Missing a '})' in the last line. I can't edit directly because it's less than 6 characters...

Comment: There is a type for attachments properties. "contents" is incorrect. should be "content".

Comment: Does this code snippet handle binary files or only text?

Comment: Older versions of nodemailer user "contents". Be sure to check what version you're using and compare with the documentation for nodemailer at http://nodemailer.com

Comment: Anyway to send db file. I am using sqlite deployed on Heroku and on every deployment, the app get formatted. I have database.db file in my directory and want to send it using email. Coz for such I need to implement cronjob. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6):

Try with nodemailer, for example try this:

```
  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  nodemailer.SMTP = {
     host: 'mail.yourmail.com',
     port: 25,
     use_authentication: true,
     user: 'info@youdomain.com',
     pass: 'somepasswd'
   };

  var message = {   
        sender: "sender@domain.com",    
        to:'somemail@somedomain.com',   
        subject: '',    
        html: '<h1>test</h1>',  
        attachments: [  
        {   
            filename: "somepicture.jpg",    
            contents: new Buffer(data, 'base64'),   
            cid: cid    
        }   
        ]   
    };
```

finally, send the message

```
    nodemailer.send_mail(message,   
      function(err) {   
        if (!err) { 
            console.log('Email send ...');
        } else console.log(sys.inspect(err));       
    });
```

Comment: ReferenceError: data is not defined -- Am I missing a require?

Comment: i guess there is typo, its content not contents

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Nodemailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/)?

> Nodemailer supports
>
> - Unicode to use any characters
> - HTML contents as well as plain text alternative
> - **Attachments**
> - Embedded images in HTML
> - SSL (but not STARTTLS)

Answer (score 3):

Personally i use [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) rest API or [Sendgrid](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/web-api/) rest API which is the most consistent way to do it.

If you need a low level approach use https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer and set up your own smtp server (or one you have access too)

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/sending-emails-in-node

Comment: Old answer, but how is an API more consistent than a local sendmail server...?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [nodejs-phpmailer](https://github.com/shimondoodkin/nodejs-phpmailer)

Comment: he use node.js, why advice him to use a php solution ?

Comment: I think that uses node.js but is based on php, kind of slow and bad.. But I think does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use AwsSum's Amazon SES library:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

In there, there is an operation called SendEmail and SendRawEmail, the latter of which can send attachments via the service.

Comment: Don't forget to fully disclose your affiliation with projects you recommend :)

Answer (score 1):

use mailer package it is very flexible and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative library to try is [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs).

I gave some of the suggestions here a try myself but running code complained that send_mail() and sendMail() is undefined (even though I simply copy & pasted code with minor tweaks). I'm using node 0.12.4 and npm 2.10.1. I had no issues with emailjs, that just worked off the shelf for me. And it has nice wrapper around attachments, so you can attach it various ways to your liking and easily, compared to the nodemailer examples here.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer for any nodejs mail needs. It's just the best at the moment :D

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but nodemailer(`npm install nodemailer`) looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Send With express-mailer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mailer)

Send PDF -->

```
var pdf="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjM..etc"

attachments: [  {  filename: 'archive.pdf',
                  contents: new Buffer(pdf.replace(/^data:application\/(pdf);base64,/,''), 'base64')
                 }   
             ]
```

Send Image -->

```
var img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...etc'
attachments: [  
             {  
               filename: 'myImage.jpg',
               contents: new Buffer(img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/,''), 'base64')
               }   
             ]
```

Send txt -->

```
attachments: [  
             {  
               filename: 'Hello.txt',
               contents: 'hello world!'
               }   
             ]
```

Comment: Can you also provide a minimal example code. Like this the answer is not very helpful since I have no idea where `attachments` should be placed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use official api of google for this.
They have provided package for node for this purpose.
[google official api](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)

Ive attached part of my code that did the attachment thing for me

```js
function makeBody(subject, message) {
var boundary = "__myapp__";
var nl = "\n";
var attach = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../"+fileName)) .toString("base64");
// console.dir(attach);
var str = [

        "MIME-Version: 1.0",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit",
        "to: " + receiverId,
        "subject: " + subject,
        "Content-Type: multipart/alternate; boundary=" + boundary + nl,
        "--" + boundary,
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" + nl,
        message+ nl,
        "--" + boundary,
        "--" + boundary,
        "Content-Type: Application/pdf; name=myPdf.pdf",
        'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myPdf.pdf',
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + nl,
        attach,
        "--" + boundary + "--"

    ].join("\n");

    var encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
    return encodedMail;
}
```

P.S thanks to [himanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2385297/himanshu) for his intense research on this

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not updated with the last version of `nodemailer@6.x`

Here an updated example:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.libero.it',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'email@libero.it',
    pass: 'HelloWorld'
  }
})


fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test22.csv'), function (err, data) {
  transport.sendMail({
    from: 'email_from@libero.it',
    to: 'email_to@libero.it',
    subject: 'Attachment',
    text: 'mail content...', // or body: field
    attachments: [{ filename: 'attachment.txt', content: data }]
  }, function (err, success) {    
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.log(err)
      return
    }
    console.log({ success })
  })
})
```