# How to send an email from a form such as a contact form, with attachments

Tags: node.js, express

Im making a web app, using node.js, express.js and mongodb  and trying get my contact form done. I would like site visitors to contact me via the form where they can put their name, email and message, along with an uploadable file image so they can show me what they want to be done as a sample through an image.

It seems like every websites have this functionailiry but I cant seem to find the answer Im looking for. Any help and guides would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it you don't know how to do, uploading files or sending mails?

Comment: uploading files

Answer (score 1):

i think you could use this library i've just found for uploading files with Javascript by using a file dialog: https://fineuploader.com/demos.

I think your issue is pretty much solved after that because for what concerns the form, you may easily create the input tags in HTML and then get data from them by using NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

To upload files you need to use a form-data handler. I use multer:

```sh
npm i multer
```

You upload a file like this:

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads' })

app.post('/profile', upload.single('image'), (req, res)) {
   //Now the image is uploaded in uploads folder you just need to send it back
}
```

Note that image is a form's input name.

For infroamtion on how to send the image see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11742613/11072506)

Look also at the docs for [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

If you don't want to store image you can use then fs  module to delete it.